# How do I display headers in reports even if the dataset is empty

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a simple report that has this structure

[image]

The report spans horizontal with different movie titles from the dataset.

The issue I'm having is that when the dataset returns an empty set of results the report is a single empty cell.

[image]

Is there any way to have the row headers to display even if the dataset returns null? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-to-keep-the-structure-of-the-tablix-when-there-is-no-data-to-show/48846#48846?

*Unlike* that answer, you probably will have to do this on the **Title** column group.

Right-click the Title column group, and then click **Add Group** > **Adjacent Before...** or **Adjacent After...**

---

### Text from that answer:

You can add a row outside of the outermost group right under the tablix header row.

{image}

Set the row visibility to Show or hide based on an expression. The expression would like like:

```
=IIf(CountRows("DataSet1") > 0, true, false)
```

When there is no data, the table will show the headers and empty row.

{another image}

When there is data, the empty row will be hidden.